# ASP.NET json.Net xml to json

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I tried to convert some xml Code in my Webpage. So I tried to using json.net.
All worked well until I tried to display my string hello. My aspx.cs Site looks like this:

**aspx.cs**

```
public partial class json : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account account = new Account
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Email = "john@microsoft.com",
            DOB = new DateTime(1980, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        };
        string hello = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
        }
}
```

And my aspx Site looks like this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="json.aspx.cs" Inherits="json" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div><% = this.hello %></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do that I can use the string "hello".

Thanks and have a good day :D

Comment: What's the error or exception you get?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'json_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'hello' and no extension method 'hello' accepting a first argument of type 'json_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have access to **hello** variable.
You can solve it by creating property **Hello**

Something like this

```
    public class Account
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }

    public string Hello { get; set; }

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Account account = new Account
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Email = "john@microsoft.com",
            DOB = new DateTime(1980, 2, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
        };
        this.Hello = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
    }
```

And on your page, you can call it

```
<div><% = this.Hello %></div>
```

Comment: But why can't I use it when it already was public. Great Answer btw.

Comment: It's not public. property `string hello` is in the scope of `Page_Load` method and doesn't belong to `json` class itself. And your aspx page doesn't see it. You have access to the `json` class and all it's public and protected properties and fields.